# DateTime validation error only for a specific date

Tags: php, validation, symfony, datetime

I have a simple user profile form with a birthday field

### Entity:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="bdate", type="date")
 */
private $bdate;
```

### FormType:

```
$builder->add('bdate', 'birthday', array(
    'input'  => 'datetime',
    'widget' => 'single_text'
));
```

### Controller:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        ...
    } else {
        // always here when 28 May 1972 
    }
}
```

It always works but when date is 1972-05-28 I have the validation error 
**This value is not valid.**

**ONLY** when 28 May 1972

With MySql it works but my database is Oracle.
I'm using listener OracleSessionInit and I haven't others problem with that.

Could you please help me? I'm being crazy

Comment: You should probably also tag your question with whatever language your code is in, as it isn't Oracle.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question on StackOverflow, I removed Oracle tag and added php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is confirmed for every date in which daylight saving time change happened exactly at midnight, which was the case for Europe/Rome from 1966 to 1979:

https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/italy/rome

This bug in Fedora Linux 15 is probably connected:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1057104

It appears to happen on current ubuntu and windows too.

PHP code to reproduce the issue:

```
<?php
$argh = "1972-05-28";
$timezone = "Europe/Rome";
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'it',
    IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    $timezone,
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    'yyyy-MM-dd'
);
echo 'lenient of the formatter is : ';
if ($fmt->isLenient()) {
    echo 'TRUE';
} else {
    echo 'FALSE';
}
$fmt->parse($argh);
echo "\n Trying to do parse($argh).\nResult is : " . $fmt->parse($argh);
if (intl_get_error_code() != 0) {
    echo "\nError_msg is : " . intl_get_error_message();
    echo "\nError_code is : " . intl_get_error_code();
}

$fmt->setLenient(FALSE);
echo "\nNow lenient of the formatter is : ";
if ($fmt->isLenient()) {
    echo 'TRUE';
} else {
    echo 'FALSE';
}
$fmt->parse($argh);
echo "\n Trying to do parse($argh).\nResult is : " . $fmt->parse($argh);
if (intl_get_error_code() != 0) {
    echo "\nError_msg is : " . intl_get_error_message();
    echo "\nError_code is : " . intl_get_error_code();
}

?>
```

A possible work-around is set timezone to different one that never changes exactly at midnight i.e. "Europe/Paris".

Answer (score 0):

Not only is the code not Oracle, neither is the error message.  But since you reference a "good" value and a "bad" value for a "date" I'll assume the invalid value is for a date.  You are probably confusing a string data with an actual DATE data type.  What you show as a "date" is actually nothing more than a string of characters that you recognize as a date but when it gets down to a sql statement processed by a database, there must be a rule on how to interpret that string.  In oracle this is done with either setting the NLS_DATE_FORMATE, or (better, in my opinion) using the TO_DATE function.